# Django - How to work with multiple ModelForm's in the same form?

Tags: python, django, modelform, django-forms

I've 4 models that I need to store data at once. For that I'm thinking using ModelForms.

I've tested with 2 ModelForm's at the same time but it is not working. Here is the code.

Model:

```
class Main(models.Model):
    section             = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    user                = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title               = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date_inserted       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_last_update    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

    # To order in the admin by name of the section
    class Meta:
    ordering = ['date_inserted']


class BicycleAd(models.Model):
    main                = models.ForeignKey(Main)
    bicycleadtype       = models.ForeignKey(BicycleAdType)
    bicycleaditemkind   = models.ForeignKey(BicycleAdItemKind) # MPTT Model
    bicycleadcondition  = models.ForeignKey(BicycleAdCondition)
    country             = models.ForeignKey(GeonamesCountry)       
    city                = models.ForeignKey(GeonamesLocal) 
    date_inserted       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_last_update    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # To order in the admin by name of the section
    class Meta:
    ordering = ['date_inserted']
```

Forms:

```
class MainForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Main
    exclude = ('user', 'section')

class BicycleAdForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = BicycleAd
    exclude = ('main', 'bicycleadtype', 'bicycleaditemkind', 'bicycleadcondition', 'city')
```

View:

```
def submit_data_entry_view(request):
    form_main      = MainForm(request.POST)
    form_bicyclead = BicycleAdForm(request.POST)

    return render_to_response('app/submit_data_entry.html', {'form_main': form_main, 'form_bicyclead': form_bicyclead}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{form_main}}
    {{form_bicyclead}}
</form>
```

At the end I only get the"form_bicyclead" outputed in the browser? How can I get the two forms at once?

Best Regards,

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: Then I would implore you to revisit your code and update it using the class based views, they take a bit of learning but they really do shine when you get the hang of them. Just a tip, I'll see if i can get back to you with an answer! :)

Comment: I'd suggest when rendering multiple forms on a single page to use the `prefix` option to each form to avoid possibility of field name clashes between the different models.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.prefix (This shouldn't be causing your issue here, just another tip).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you using `submit_data_entry_view` to render forms too? shouldn't it be like -

```
def submit_data_entry_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST': #form submit
        form_main      = MainForm(request.POST)
        form_bicyclead = BicycleAdForm(request.POST)

        #now process and save the form

        return <whatever_you_want>
    elif request.method == 'GET': #first time rendering the form
        form_main      = MainForm()
        form_bicyclead = BicycleAdForm()

        return render_to_response('app/submit_data_entry.html', {'form_main': form_main, 'form_bicyclead': form_bicyclead}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```